# Using a static MSVC 2010 libary (.lib) with MinGW?

Tags: mingw, static-libraries, visual-studio-2010, .a, .lib

Since a few WIN32 related things didn't quite work using MinGW, I decided to  create a small static library with MSVC 2010 and link it with MinGW afterwards. However, I am currently looking for a tool that allows me to convert static MSVC libraries(.lib) to MinGW static libraries(.a). Searching the web, I have found various tools such as "lib to a", which requires a .dll file for some reason, so I figured it was not quite what I was looking for.

The library is compiled in C and works perfectly using MSVC.
This is the header file:

```
#ifndef _GWSI_H
#define _GWSI_H

#include <Windows.h>

#define GWSI_HEIGHT             0x0001
#define GWSI_WIDTH              0x0002

#define GWSI_OSVI_MAJOR         0x0010
#define GWSI_OSVI_MINOR         0x0011
#define GWSI_OSVI_BUILD         0x0012

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

float GWSI_getCpuSpeed();
int GWSI_getOSV(unsigned int flag);
int GWSI_getScreenResolution(unsigned int flag);
unsigned _int64 GWSI_getTotalSystemMemory();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif



#endif /*_GWSI_H*/
```

The attempt of simply trying to link the .lib, pretending it was an .a, (using Netbeans with MinGW and not VisualStudio, of course) led to this error:

```
GWSI.h:26:17: error: expected initializer before GWSI.h:26:17: error: expected initializer before 'GWSI_getTotalSystemMemory'
```

After removing the 'GWSI_getTotalSystemMemory();' prototype I got this error, which I assume means that the library was not linked to begin with:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `GWSI_getCpuSpeed'
```

Do you have any idea on how I could achieve my goal, of using this static library with MinGW? Also, what could possibly have caused the first error? I can't see any invalid deceleration.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your first error is a compiler error: `_int64` should be `__int64`. The second is indeed a linker error. What command (`gcc ....`) did you use to link? And what Win32 related things did not work with MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't link libraries compiled in MSVC to your MinGW code.

Comment: Yes, you can, you just have to be careful to link with the right msvcr*.dll.